# Python NDB: Property validation in queries?

Tags: python, validation, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I have a model:

```
def category_path_validator(prop , val):
    # makes sure the path is of the form `first.second(...)last`
    # and that it represents a valid path in the category tree.
    pass

class Product(ndb.Model):
    category_path = nsb.StringProperty(validator=category_path_validator)
```

I want to be able to get all `Products` within a category so my query is:

```
Product.Query(ndb.AND(Product.category_path >= 'furniture' , Product.category_path <= 'furniturez'))
```

(adding the `z` works since `<=,>=` compares strings lexicography )

now this produces an error because `furniturez` is not a valid category.

Is there a way to `query` the value **without** `validation` , but still be able to set the property **with** `validation` ?

Comment: This is a symptom of the wider problem you can have with validators.  I am not convinced they are a good idea at the property level. If you ever change you validation business rules in the future and preexisting data no longer meets the validation criteria you can run into all sort of problems.

Comment: you're right ,didn't think of that , maybe validators are not a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way is to split the validation into two parts.  The first part is to simplify your validator to only check the `StringProperty`:

```
def category_path_validator(prop , val):
    # makes sure the path is of the form `first.second(...)last`
    pass
```

The second part is to add a [Model hook](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/entities#hooks):

```
def _pre_put_hook(self):
    # makes sure that category_path represents a valid path in the category tree.
    pass
```

The downside is that you won't know if the `category_path` is bad until you try and `put()` it.